# Query to calculate time between multiple trips

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table that stores the number of trip and type of trip made for a given day by a driver as follows

```
Date           Delivery        Pick-up
====           ========        =======
01/01/2013     5               0
```

We also have an attendance table that stores the driver attendance as follows.

```
AttDate        InTime         OutTIme       THours
=======        ======         =======       ======
01/01/2013     10:00          13:00         3
```

How do I calculate the average time between the 5 trip using the employee Thours using MSSQL 2008/2012?.  This is for performance monitoring purpose.

Comment: Are you saying to take `THours` / `Delivery` by `Date`?

Comment: Hi, Yes..  That is correct..

Comment: how do you know the rows are from the same driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have some sort of `driver_id`, which you'll have to add to the join, or, as @Randy points out, you won't be able to determine which rows belong to which drivers.
Here's the general form of the query:

```
SELECT Trip.business_day, 
       DATEDIFF(minute, arrivedAt, leftBy) / CASE WHEN deliveries = 0
                                                  THEN 1
                                                  ELSE deliveries END 
                            as average_deliveries_in_minutes
FROM Trip
JOIN Driver_Attendence
  ON Driver_Attendence.business_day = Trip.business_day
```

([working SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/373e4/3))
You didn't actually list what you wanted to do `deliveries = 0` is true - the `CASE` is there so you don't get 'divide-by-zero' errors.  Excluding drivers without any deliveries would allow you to remove the case, and just reference the column.

Comment: Hello, Yes.  We do have a column for the driver ID, and also, the Zero actually forms part of the total 5 trip.  ie, 5 trip made for the day, and none of the 5 trip were pick-up..  They are not separate trip.  I will give your solution a try.  Thanks Guys!!.. :)